# Diode Connected MOS

Tags: transistors, mosfet, analog, circuit-design, cmos

let's consider the equivalent circuit of a diode connected Mosfet.

Since the current source between drain and source is:

gm * Vgs = gm * Vds

and it is proportional to Vds, it means that this current source behaves like a resistor of value 1/gm.

Now I have two questions:
- a diode connected Mosfet works in saturation, that means as a controlled source. How is it possible that it behave like a resistor (which is what will happen in triode region)? 
- Mosfets used as amplifiers need to be polarized in saturation in order to generate a current which is controlled by a voltage signal. So may be a diode connected Mosfet useful for an amplifier? Or is it just like a resistor and so unuseful for that aim?

Comment: Try read this https://www.ittc.ku.edu/~jstiles/412/handouts/6.5%20The%20Common%20Source%20Amp%20with%20Active%20loads/section%206_5%20The%20Common%20Source%20Amp%20with%20Active%20Loads%20lecture.pdf

Comment: Any more questions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How is it possible that it behave like a resistor (which is what will
>   happen in triode region)?

You can’t equate it to the triode region unless you are holding Vgs at some fixed value and, you can’t do that because Vgs = Vds when wired as a MOSFET diode.

> may be a diode connected Mosfet useful for an amplifier?

If it’s connected as a diode there are only two terminals and this means, I suspect that it is impossible for it to be an amplifier (else we’d be using regular diodes like this all the time).